# How to overload python sets to accept duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x, set, overloading

I had taken a python coding test, which asked to create a class that overloads the builtin set(all the methods of sets must work). The only change between the set I was asked to create and the builtin sets is that my custom sets SHOULD store duplicates, and 2 more custom methods.

Here is what I could come up with:

```
import builtins

class Multiset(builtins.set):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_set = builtins.set()

    def add(self, val):
        self.my_set.add(val)

    def remove(self, val):
        # removes one occurrence of val from the multiset, if any
        self.my_set.discard(val)

    def __contains__(self, val):
        # returns True when val is in the multiset, else returns False
        return val in self.my_set

    def __len__(self):
        # returns the number of elements in the multiset
        return len(self.my_set)
```

I have tried overriding multiple methods, but to no avail. I also couldn't find a method that defined this non-duplicate criteria for sets. So, how do I do this?

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the problem description, if you want to see it.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary which maps objects to a list of all objects that are equal to themselves. The advantage is that `dict` keys are already set-like.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class MultiSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items = defaultdict(list)

    def add(self, item):
        self._items[item].append(item)

    def remove(self, item):
        try:
            self._items[item].remove(item)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._items

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(len(v) for v in self._items.values())
```

Comment: Why not use a `collections.Counter`?

Comment: @DanielWalker This is also possible though slightly different. `Counter` throws away the actual objects and just counts their occurrences. In most cases this should be fine since most likely object equality is the only thing that a user relies on. However since `1 == 1.0` if you do `s.add(1); s.add(1.0)` and then iterate over `s` you'll get `1` two times. With a list of objects you can get back the actual objects namely `1` and `1.0`. But as mentioned, since they are equal this difference most likely doesn't matter. Why don't you add the `Counter` approach as a separate answer?

Comment: @a_guest, this is a nice one. But, this doesn't "overload" any methods. and also methods of sets doesn't work too.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Indeed these still need to be implemented. But it shouldn't be too difficult, starting from the four methods that are already present.